# Order script injection in GWT using Scriptinjector

Tags: gwt, javascript-injection

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="public/rappid.min.css" />
<script src="public/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="public/lodash.js"></script>
<script src="public/backbone.js"></script>
<script src="public/rappid.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="public/joint.ui.tooltip.min.css" />
<script src="public/joint.ui.tooltip.min.js"></script>
```

I want this order for scripts injection, but when i am using scriptinjector, they are loaded randomly and giving error like this.

```
backbone.js:382 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined(…)(anonymous function) @ backbone.js:382(anonymous function) @           
 backbone.js:31(anonymous function) @ backbone.js:34
ConsoleLogger.java:32 backbone.js Loaded
ConsoleLogger.java:32 jquery.js Loaded
joint.layout.treeLayout.min.js:14 Uncaught ReferenceError: joint is not defined(…)(anonymous function) @ joint.layout.treeLayout.min.js:14
ConsoleLogger.java:32 joint.layout.treeLayout.min.js Loaded
callgraph.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: joint is not defined(…)(anonymous function) @ callgraph.js:1
ConsoleLogger.java:32 callgraph.js Loaded
rappid.min.css:15 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
ConsoleLogger.java:32 rappid.min.css Loaded
ConsoleLogger.java:32 lodash.js Loaded
rappid.min.js:43 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '$' of undefined(…)(anonymous function) @ rappid.min.js:43(anonymous function) @ rappid.min.js:50
ConsoleLogger.java:32 rappid.min.js Loaded
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to load/inject the next script from the callback signaling the previous one is ready.